# Docker Container (ToolJet) Crashes immediately without logs

Tags: docker, containers

I have been working with ToolJet and using docker to host this for a while now, and this command

```
docker run --name tooljet --restart unless-stopped -p 80:80 -v tooljet_data:/var/lib/postgresql/13/main tooljet/try:latest
```

has always worked, but now when I run it, it just puts the container in a constant state of restarting.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is some output from the `docker stats` and `docker inspect` commands

```
docker stats tooljet:
CONTAINER ID   NAME      CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %     NET I/O   BLOCK I/O   PIDS
c5497278497a   tooljet   0.00%     0B / 0B             0.00%     0B / 0B   0B / 0B     0
```

```
docker inspect tooljet:
[
    {
        "Id": "c5497278497aaa6855a3c92e43708ba67f910f20ceef7110f2d75cc2b11c9a40",
        "Created": "2023-04-12T22:45:26.89779537Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "service postgresql start 1\u003e /dev/null \u0026\u0026 /usr/bin/supervisord"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "restarting",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": true,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 1,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-04-12T22:48:18.701990763Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2023-04-12T22:48:18.946159478Z"
        },
        "Name": "/tooljet",
        "RestartCount": 12,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "tooljet_data:/var/lib/postgresql/13/main"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                26,
                273
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "c5497278497a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "root",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
               "PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NODE_ENV=production",
                "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096",
                "TOOLJET_HOST=http://localhost",
                "PORT=80",
                "LOCKBOX_MASTER_KEY=replace_with_lockbox_master_key",
                "SECRET_KEY_BASE=replace_with_secret_key_base",
                "PG_DB=tooljet_production",
                "PG_USER=tooljet",
                "PG_PASS=postgres",
                "PG_HOST=localhost",
                "ENABLE_TOOLJET_DB=true",
                "TOOLJET_DB_HOST=localhost",
                "TOOLJET_DB_USER=tooljet",
                "TOOLJET_DB_PASS=postgres",
                "TOOLJET_DB=tooljet_db",
                "PGRST_HOST=http://localhost:3000",
                "PGRST_DB_URI=postgres://tooljet:postgres@localhost/tooljet_db",
                "ORM_LOGGING=true",
                "DEPLOYMENT_PLATFORM=docker:local",
                "TERM=xterm"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "tooljet/try:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "service postgresql start 1\u003e /dev/null \u0026\u0026 /usr/bin/supervisord"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        }
   ...
```

I have updated my Docker Desktop, I have deleted the container and image and redownloaded them, I have ran this without `--restart unless-stopped` and it just crashes the container immediately, and I have read all of the stackoverflow threads regarding similar issues to no avail. I also might add that running `docker logs tooljet` doesn't print anything.